# lftp in shell script fails with "pseudo-tty allocation failed" only when run via cronjob

Tags: linux, shell-script, sftp, cron, lftp

I am trying to create a shell script which copies a file to a foreign server using SFTP (because SSH is not available on the foreign server). The script works as expected when run via console, but it quits with a fatal error when run via cronjob:

The **lftp command** is like

`/usr/bin/lftp -d -e "set sftp:auto-confirm yes; open sftp://$user:$pass@$server_address; put $local_filepath -o $remote_filename; bye;" >> "backup.log"`

The **output** when run via cronjob is like

```
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l xxxxx sftp.yyyyy.com sftp)
put: /home/zzzzz/filename.txt: Fatal error: pseudo-tty allocation failed: No such file or directory
```

I found out that it is not possible to disable pseudo-tty alloaction in lftp, but why does it work when run via console then?

Apart from that, is there another common program I can use to copy the file using SFTP? I am on a shared hosting server and have no root rights though, so I cannot install any software.

Comment: You can try `sftp`, `scp`